# Move git project from local to remote, how?

Tags: git

I'd like to move my current git porject from local machine to remote machine.
All development I will do at my local machine. So I have to have ability to checkout branches from remote machine to my local via `git://`

What shoud I do to make `git://` protocol working on my remote machine? How can I protect it from being connected from third party?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You know Git runs over SSH by default? It would be much easier on you to use this secure functionality that's already there.

Set up a git ssh account on your remote machine and then store your repository where you like. Then set the origin in .git to be the location of your repo, eg. ssh://git@yourhost/var/git/repolocation

From here you can "git clone", "git push", "git pull" the repo as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I would use github to host the code.

http://help.github.com/security/

Comment: This would probably make the project public, wouldn't it ?

Comment: You can pay for private repositories.